# Hibernate JPA Criteria - how to join with subquery

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, jpa, subquery, hibernate-criteria

I have two tables `Author` and `Book` with relationship one-many.

Now I want to list all authors with total of books in a particular country.

I use SQL Sever, this is my query.

```
SELECT Author.id, Author.name, Author.age, subTbl.total
FROM Author INNER JOIN (SELECT Book.authorId, COUNT(*) AS total FROM Book GROUP BY Book.authorId) subTbl
ON Author.authorId = subTbl.authorId
WHERE Author.countryId = 'en';
```

I know that we can write this query in another way without using SubQuery but I want to try SubQuery with CriteriaQuery to write this query.

I have searched further, but there are only examples of SubQuery in where expression.

Comment: What does hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria tags have to do with this question? Can you clarify your question regarding what you are trying to achieve?